# Persistent Ruby segfaulting after a clean install

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, openssl, segmentation-fault, net-http

Ruby keeps segfaulting when using the Koala gem to talk over HTTP:

```
/Users/pawel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:799: [BUG] Segmentation fault
```

I've tried the following:

- Run `which -a ruby` which showed multiple Rubies via MacPorts. So I deleted those and running the same command again returns only `/usr/bin/ruby`
- I've removed the MacPorts version of PostgreSQL and installed it with Homebrew instead (With MacPorts, it installs its own version of OpenSSL)
- Running `openssl version` returns `OpenSSL 1.0.0g 18 Jan 2012`
- I removed Ruby 1.9.3 from RVM and tried Luciano's method below which didn't work.
- I've also tried reinstalling 1.9.3 from RVM and specifying `--with-openssl-dir=/opt/local` since `which openssl` returns `/opt/local/bin/openssl`
- I've reinstalled RVM (It's now version 1.10.2 in `/Users/pawel/.rvm/bin/rvm`)
- I've upgraded to Ruby 1.9.3-p125 and have also tried on 1.9.2
- I've followed the instructions here: http://www.christopherirish.com/2011/09/02/ruby-1-9-2-segmentation-fault-and-openssl/ (which are my above steps, actually). I've also read Christopher's previous post [here](http://www.christopherirish.com/2010/06/21/ruby-1-8-7-openssl-bus-error/).
- In my project directory when I run the following then I get the expected `0`.:

  `ruby -rubygems -e" require 'eventmachine'; require 'openssl' "; echo $?`
- I've tried to `sudo port -f deactivate openssl` but then when I try to start a Rails server I get `Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib`

I need some more ideas on what else I can try, or things I've missed.

Comment: I removed `~/.rvm` dir nad installed rvm, ruby and `openssl` package from rvm (`rvm pkg install openssl`) and all started to work fine

Comment: You mean running `rvm implode`? How did your `rvm install ruby 1.9.3` flag look?

Comment: I didn't know about `implode`. I've removed rvm dir manualy `rm -rf ~/.rvm`, then install rvm again, then `rvm pkg install openssl`, `rvm pkg install iconv`, `rvm install 1.9.2 --with-openssl-dir=$rvm_path/usr --with-iconv-dir=$rvm_path/usr` (yes,It is about 1.9.2, but I don't think it makes difference)

Comment: I have tried this before, and tried it again last night, to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seemed to be that Homebrew and MacPorts were conflicting, so I deleted MacPorts, removed all packages and the `/opt/local/` directory. This caused some issue with the **PG** gem due to the PostgreSQL installation on Homebrew.

So I deleted the Postgres formula, then reinstalled it and ditto for the OpenSSL installation using Homebrew.

After that I imploded RVM and installed it and my Rubies again (not sure if this step was necessary) and finally it works.

Comment: It usually says you can only accept 2 days after submitting it. Guess that's only for fresh questions.

Answer (score 7):

I'm also getting this same Segmentation Fault error, but I'm trying to list files on AWS-S3.

**Edit**:

This way worked for me:

```
export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:$HOME/.rvm/bin
rvm remove 1.9.3 
rvm pkg install iconv
rvm pkg install openssl
rvm install ruby-1.9.3 --with-openssl-dir=~/.rvm/usr --with-iconv-dir=~/.rvm/usr
```

- as @Simpleton said, I wrote a comment in the wrong place. Now I'm editing it with a response. ;-)

Comment: Thanks this worked for me after trying similar reinstalls.  Something funny about your rvm install line, copy/pasting didn't work, maybe some special characters.  Anyway, thanks.

Comment: @Luciano Still giving you the bounty because this answer will probably work for anyone without MacPorts/Homebrew conflicts.

Comment: On Lion I had to run ```export CC=/usr/bin/gcc``` before it would compile. Found via [Jeff Douglas](http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2011/08/01/ruby-1-9-2-install-errors-with-mac-os-x-lion-and-rvm/)

Comment: I've tried various other hints as well without success - the specific PATH settings that removed the ambivalence about which openssl to use seem to make the difference and worked for me.

Comment: i needed to update RVM using `rvm get head`, then this worked great! via [Delameko](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8007305/361609)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue, too, but used a different solution. Here's the [full stack trace of the error](http://pastie.org/private/bdexgbc3klc1f77uvv7jq).

Here is the official bug report: http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/6184 The responses below the stack trace were very helpful.

> If you're using OS X's default openssl -> do like `brew install
>   openssl` and build with installed openssl, then try again.
>
> If you're using openssl that installed by user -> build with OS X default ssl and try again.

This sounded similar to an issue for me recently when the [readline library installed in MacPorts broke a ruby installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7296169/pasting-text-into-irb-is-incredibly-slow-readline-issue/9793565#9793565). Running the following script on the broken ruby installation showed it was loading the MacPorts openssl lib

```
require 'net/https'
puts `lsof -p #{$$} | grep ssl | awk '{print $9}'`
```

(the output)

```
/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin11.2.0/openssl.bundle
/opt/local/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
```

The solution was to temporarily move MacPorts out of `/opt/local` while installing ruby.

1. Quit all processes that are accessing MacPorts files. You can see which ones are running with `sudo lsof | grep /opt/local`.
2. `sudo mv /opt/local /opt/localbak`
3. Open a new terminal, then compile and install Ruby
4. `sudo mv /opt/localbak /opt/local`

After that, the ruby installation worked properly alongside MacPorts and did not load the libssl file from MacPorts.